# What is Windows Vista's equivalent for the Version tab in Properties?

Tags: dll, windows-vista, windows-server-2008

In Windows XP, whenever you right-click to select Properties to a particular DLL, you will be able to access the Version tab.

In windows Vista, there is the Details table, which had some, but not all, the usual displayable items in the Version tab. In particular, the Assembly Version is missing.

This is a head-banging problem for me right now, because I have a number of DLLs with the same file version, but different assembly versions. Right now, I can't tell the difference between them.

Is there any way I can view the Assembly Version in Vista?

P.S. This is a deployment problem in my case, because the difference between the DLLs is the Assembly Version, which I can view fine in Windows XP, but not in Windows Vista. So, I can't tell if we have the right DLLs deployed, since I can't view it in my Windows Vista machine.

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Comment: I would agree unless it involves a "deployment of his application" type of problem.

Comment: Well, I don't have access to Superuser.com, so I can't post there even if I wanted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is head-bangingly simple, as it turns out: since Windows Vista can't show the Assembly version, use a 3rd-party tool that can.

In this case, the tool is our ol' friend: [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). The assembly version, location, name & type of the DLL are displayed at the bottom of the tool.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that I've been searching for as well, and I've found a related blog post, that gives a somewhat easier solution (considering you might not be able to install applications on servers of clients):

http://all-things-pure.blogspot.com/2009/09/assembly-version-file-version-product.html

quote from the blog:

```
To see the assembly version of a file in Vista or later without writing a program, simply     type the following in Windows PowerShell:
[Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName('xxxx.dll').Version.

Where xxxx.dll is the full path of your assembly
```

Answer (score 0):

In detail view of a folder, you can right click on the bar that shows name, date modified etc to select more properties to display such as Version and Product Version.

Comment: Product Version is one of the properties displayed in the Details Tab, but isn't the Assembly Version. Version doesn't show anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio installed, you can view the DLL in the program.
Detailed information of the DLL will be shown, including the public functions/ interface, as well as the assembly version.

Comment: Can't install visual studio on user machines where the DLLs are deployed, but it does help me find the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

For the ones who use TotalCommander, install FileInfo plugin. Then Lister will show file information including AssemblyInfo.

FileInfo plugin:
http://physio-a.univ-tours.fr/tcplugins/